# Wrap Angular JS directive inside of Polymer element

Tags: angularjs, polymer

Is it possible to wrap an Angular directives in Polymer tags? Something like:

```
<polymer-element>
  <ng-dir click="{{vm.doSomething()}}" field1="{{blah}}"></ng-dir>
```

Comment: Even if you get it to work, you'll still need to include AngularJS onto the page, have an Angular module (ng-app set on a portion of the page), etc.

It's not going to be a graceful fit. The reverse (Polymer inside of an AngularJS app) would probably be better.

Comment: @John True, but I'm looking for ways to reuse what we already have for 3rd party "drop in" components to other sites. I'm looking into alternatives to Iframes...